# Deleting dynamic partition to fix windows - urgent

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning, debian

I created new volume in order to install Debian in it.
Once I succeeded.. Windows was unable to start. Freezes on Windows logo screen.

After a painful attempt of installing Debian, I just ruined my PC booting.
Then I fixed it, but the old problem still remains.

So, when I run Startup Repair, it doesn't recognize Windows 7 Installation location and it prompts cmd with the letter X:
I am a programmer, that has a lot of projects and work and I really need this fixed. I am about to just delete this partition X labeled "Boot" But it isn't displayed in DISKPART, maybe because it is "dynamic partition". I couldn't even format it, because it is "write protected".

What am I supposed to do ?

Comment: Usually with Linux it messes up the MBR I've encountered this a few times,when dual booting Linux/windows, restart pc, head into boot menu and boot to your Windows. Once in, start a command prompt with administrator privileges and check out the BCDedit commands (research first)

Comment: Rebuild the BCD http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm

Comment: I rebuilt it, which is what most likely fixed the non-booting windows. But.. how do I get rid of the windows logo stuck ?